# Not Able To Use STL's string class

Tags: c++, string, stl

Encountered this problem before but forgot how I solved it.

I want to use the STL string class but the complier is complaining about not finding it.
Here is the complete .h file.

```
#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H

#include "../shared/gltools.h"  // OpenGL toolkit
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "Types.h"

class Model
{

public:

    obj_type_ptr p_object;
    char Load3DS (char *p_filename);
    int LoadBitmap(char *filename);

    int num_texture;
    string fun("alex");

    Model(char* modelName, char* textureFileName);
};

#endif
```

Comment: can't find the include file? odd....

Comment: Please include compiler error messages. It looks to me like you aren't prefixing string with std:: in the header file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to be using `std::string`, yes?

You're just using `string`. Which works if you have a `using namespace ...` declaration, but isn't really a good idea in a header file.

Comment: …and there are a couple ways to get it other than `using namespace`.

Comment: Anon, why it's not a good idea to use "using namespace" in a header file?

Comment: @Lipis, Because every source file that includes the header will end up "using namespace" as well, which is usually not what you want - ie the namespace gets propagated throughout the project and ends up getting diluted value as a symbol-uniqueness-enhancer.

Comment: So "using namespace" only inside the source files :) On the other hand though, according to many people it's not a really good practice to use them at all. Thanks Justicle

Comment: @Lipis: Yeah, depends on how strict you are. Any time you have `using namespace xyz`, you risk name collisions. Some people think it's best to be strict and just never do `using namespace` at all. Some just avoid it at namespace scope (but allow it inside functions), and some allow it in .cpp files but not .h. I tend to follow the second approach (no `using namespace`s, except inside functions, where the effect is limited and doesn't pollute other code)

Comment: But it's not kinda annoying to write `std::` before `cout` all the time? And what about Potatoswatter's approach?

Comment: @Lipis, I will do `using ::std::string` inside functions or in a .cpp file.  I very rarely or never do `using namespace foo;`.  Importing specific names is much nicer and has more predictable results than importing a whole namespace of names.

Answer (score 3):

Every identifier in the STL is in the `std` namespace. Until you do `using namespace std;`, `using std::string;`, or `typedef std::string xxx;`, it must be called `std::string`.

Any kind of `using` declaration in a header, especially outside your own namespace, is a bad idea, as others have mentioned.

So, import `std::string` into your class:

```
class Model
{
    typedef std::string string;

    public:
```

Comment: You'll never know! But since I happened across the answer, +1 for it.

Answer (score 1):

ohhh, std::string. Never use the using namespace in a header file btw.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the namespace issue mentioned by other answers, you can't construct a variable at its declaration as a class member.  Assuming you changed it to

```
class Model {
    // ...
    std::string fun("alex");
};
```

This is still illegal inside a class, you cannot assign a value in the declaration, you have to leave it:

```
class Model {
    // ...
    std::string fun;
};
```

And if you want to give it "alex" when it is created, initialise it in the constructor:

```
Model::Model(...)
    : fun("alex")  // initialiser
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `std::string fun = "alex" is perfectly valid, and initializes the variable when it's declared. you can, and usually should, assign a value immediately when constructing a variable.

Comment: I was referring to when declaring it as a class member, because only static const integral data members can be initialised like that, which doesn't include string.  Edited answer to clarify this.